# General solution $x$ to $Ax = 0$ for matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following matrix
 $$A = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  -1-3i & -8-10i & 0-3i \\
  -7-3i & -4-9i & -3-2i \\
  11-3i & -16-12i & 6-5i
\end{array}
\right] $$

Find the general solution x to Ax = 0.

I am confused by what the "general" solution means; does anyone have any hints as to how to start solving this problem?

Comment: Do you know how to reduce a matrix to row-reduced echelon form? If not, learn! :)

Comment: I do know! The issue for me is interpreting what the question is asking for.

Comment: They're asking for the solution written in terms of free variables (coming from the non-pivot columns of the reduced echelon form). For example, if your reduced echelon form is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 1 & b \end{bmatrix}$, then you write the equations $x_1+ax_3=x_2+bx_3=0$ and get the general solutiion $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_3(-a,-b,1)$.

Comment: You need to find $\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ such that $A\vec{x} = (0, 0, 0) = \vec{0}$. You do this by Gauss-Jordan elimination, aka put it in reduced row echelon form. This is a linear system of equations, if you don't know how to solve one, check out some examples on YouTube or some introductory Linear Algebra book, such as Howard Anton.

Comment: Ok, these comments alone are extremely helpful (and what i suspected).

Comment: One more comment before you go: Solving $Ax = 0$ for $x$, means that you are looking for the Null Space of your matrix. So I'd search on YouTube for "null space matrix calculate", or something like that.

Comment: Oh, I remember null space! Definitely will look at that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general solution is a set of all possible solutions to the given equation. Here we need to perform Gaussian elimination to get a row-reduced form of $A$; I got (using SymPy)
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&\frac1{7730}(4001-597i)\\
0&1&\frac1{3865}(218+464i)\\
0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
The general solution remains the same with this reduced $A$, so it is
$$(x,y,z)=\left\{\left(-\frac1{7730}(4001-597i)z,-\frac1{3865}(218+464i)z,z\right):z\in\mathbb C\right\}$$

Comment: Ok, I arrived at a similar solution. However, why do you have  next to all three terms? Shouldn't it be x,y and z?

Comment: @Workhorse The solution has one degree of freedom because I reduced $A$ to a matrix with one zero row. That free variable I denote here by $z$.